# javascript shifting issue (rgb and rgba to hex)

Tags: javascript

I found a RGB to hex converter and I'm trying to make a RGBA to hex converter. The original `rgb2hex` function works but the new `rgba2hex` function does not. What am I doing wrong? The rgba function is returning gba, no r.

```
// convert RGB color data to hex
function rgb2hex(r, g, b) {
    if (r > 255 || g > 255 || b > 255)
        throw "Invalid color component";
    return ((r << 16) | (g << 8) | b).toString(16);
}

// convert RGBA color data to hex
function rgba2hex(r, g, b, a) {
    if (r > 255 || g > 255 || b > 255 || a > 255)
        throw "Invalid color component";
    return ((r << 32) | (g << 16) | (b << 8) | a).toString(16);
}
```

Example:

```
alert(rgb2hex(255, 155, 055));
alert(rgba2hex(255, 155, 055, 255));
```

Current output: `ff9b2d` and  `9b2dff`

Expected output:`ff9b2d` and  `ff9b2dff`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your issue is that bitwise math in JavaScript caps out at 31 bits, so you can't quite do this as is.  You need to use normal math ops, not bitwise ops:

```
// convert RGBA color data to hex
function rgba2hex(r, g, b, a) {
    if (r > 255 || g > 255 || b > 255 || a > 255)
        throw "Invalid color component";
    return (256 + r).toString(16).substr(1) +((1 << 24) + (g << 16) | (b << 8) | a).toString(16).substr(1);
}
```

Also fixed an issue with the original algorithm where if the first component is < 10, the output doesn't have enough digits.

Anyway, this won't work anyway... `#ff9b2dff` isn't a valid color, but you may not care?

Answer (score 0):

RGB to HEX

```
 rgb(0 255 94)
 rgb(0, 255, 94)
```

RGBA to HEX

```
 rgba(255,25,2,0.5)
 rgba(255 25 2 / 0.5)
 rgba(50%,30%,10%,0.5)
 rgba(50%,30%,10%,50%)
 rgba(50% 30% 10% / 0.5)
 rgba(50% 30% 10% / 50%)
```

[DEMO](https://codepen.io/pedro404/pen/zYdYwKE) - CODEPEN.IO