# How can I convert rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.8) to a normal #000000 type color?

Tags: html, css

My web site uses the following and similar:

```
rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.8)
```

Is there a simple way I can convert this to the # notation?

Comment: Any reason why you want to do that?

Comment: http://hex2rgba.devoth.com/ there you go :)

Comment: You can still use for example rgba(44, 33, 22, 1) , so simple change color with opacity in it/

Comment: As far as I know, that's not possible. You'd have to strip opacity info.

Comment: Definitely you will find your solution here:

<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9765618/javascript-shifting-issue-rgb-and-rgba-to-hex>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the RGB values with any RGB-to-Hex tool, and then add an `opacity` CSS attribute.

Example converter: http://www.javascripter.net/faq/rgbtohex.htm

Example usage: `opacity:0.5; color:#00000`

Comment: This looks quite the same, but the opacity will apply to the whole element then (also text in it), not just the color. but you can apply the opacity to the color assuming it is on white background and use the resulting color ("flattened"): https://filosophy.org/code/online-tool-to-lighten-color-without-alpha-channel/