# Convert RGB/RGBA to hex make opacity of rgba not ignored?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this color with transparency:

```
rgba(150, 117, 117, 0.31);
```

My question is how can I convert the color rgba to hexa?

Comment: Assuming by 'hexa' you mean a hexadecimal colour reference with an alpha channel, then there's no such thing; at least not in CSS. If you just want plain hex, then use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9765618/javascript-shifting-issue-rgb-and-rgba-to-hex)

Answer (score 0):

Would moving the 0.31 to the css opacity setting be what you need?

So:

```
color: rgb(150, 117, 117);
color: #967575;
opacity: 0.31;
```

Or, are you looking for a formula to do this?