# Receive incorrect alpha channel when convert rgba color to hex

Tags: javascript, hex, rgb, rgba

In order to convert rgba color with alpha channel to hex I use the code

```js
let rChannel = 255;
let gChannel = 255;
let bChannel = 255;
let aChannel = 0.7;

console.log('#'+(256 + parseFloat(rChannel)).toString(16).substr(1) + ((1 << 24) + (parseFloat(gChannel) << 16) | (parseFloat(bChannel) << 8) | aChannel).toString(16).substr(1));
// #ffffff00, but expect #ffffffb3
```

It's given from the answer by the link https://stackoverflow.com/a/9766195/3208225

But it returns incorrect alpha channel in hex (00 instead of b3).

How to fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a bitwise `|` (or) operator on a floating-point value does not make sense. You'll have to use `~~(achannel * 255)` to get an integer value.

Depending on the range of your 0 ... 1 achannel values, you might want to use 256 instead of 255 if the value can never be 1.

*edit* — now that I think about it, you don't need the `~~` explicit integer conversion, because the `|` will do that anyway, so simply `(achannel * 256)` will work so long as the fractional value will always be less than 1; otherwise 255.

Comment: Could you write the whole line?

Comment: I substituting `(achannel * 256)` for just `achannel` really that difficult?

Comment: Ok, I've got it `...) | (aChannel * 256)).toString(...`

Comment: @stckvrw here you go `console.log('#'+(256 + (rChannel)).toString(16).substr(1) + ((1 << 24) + ((gChannel) << 16) | ((bChannel) << 8) | (aChannel * 256)).toString(16).substr(1));`